# Projection of a discrete subgroup of $R^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, discrete-mathematics, vector-spaces

Let $A$ be a discrete subgroup of $\Bbb R^n$ and let $V$ be a $m<n$ dimensional $\Bbb R$-subspace of $\Bbb R^n$. Is the projection of $A$ onto $V$ a discrete subgroup? I am most interested in the case of $m=1$.

Edit: I want the subspace to contain a non trivial element of $A$, you can assume this element has minimal norm if necessary(any of the norms that generate the usual topology will do).

Note that the result is not true for arbitrary discrete subsets of $\Bbb R^n$. $S = \{(2^{1/n},n)\subset \Bbb R^2\}$ projected onto $V = \{(x,0)|x \in \Bbb R\}$ is a counter example in this case.

This has been answered at : [Subgroups of $\Bbb{R}^n$ that are closed and discrete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186998/subgroups-of-bbbrn-that-are-closed-and-discrete?rq=1)

Comment: Project the integer lattice in $\mathbb R^2$ onto a line through the origin with irrational slope.

Comment: @lulu Sorry, I forgot to include the condition that $|V \cup \Bbb R^n| >  1$.

Comment: There is a general result if $G$ is a discrete additive subgroup, then $G = \mathbb{Z}e_1 + \mathbb{Z}e_2 + \ldots + \mathbb{Z}e_d$ for some $R$- basis $\{ e_i\}$ and $d \leq n$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha$ be an irrational number and consider the line, L, defined by $y=\alpha x$. We want to project the integer lattice onto L.  The usual calculation shows that the point (m,n) is projected to the point:
$$\frac{m+n\alpha}{{1+\alpha^2}}\;(1,\,\alpha)$$
But $\alpha$ is irrational so the set of points {$m+n\alpha\;\;\;m,n \in \mathbb  Z$} is dense.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include a condition. I want the subspace to contain a non zero point of the lattice(or even an element of minimal norm).

Comment: Maybe I am tired but in that case can I not  consider the lattice $\Lambda = \left( (m,n\alpha) \;\;\; m,n\in \mathbb Z \right)$?  projecting onto $y= \alpha x$ with have the same form only with $m+n\alpha^2$ in the numerator so just require that $\alpha^2$ be irrational.  Doesn't that still give a counterexample?

Comment: yes you are probably correct.

Comment: it turns out, if you choose the subspace to be generated by the element of minimum norm, everything goes through as shown here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/187028/68188